# How to use JAXB with PropertyChangeSupport?

Tags: jaxb, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to use JAXB in an Eclipse project. View widgets are bound to model attributes with java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport. This works fine. I want to also bind model attributes to a persistent XML representation on disk with JAXB.  I can marshal important state to XML and can unmarshal that back into a pojo/bean thing at runtime but am not sure how best to proceed.

1. The bean setters bound to my view widgets need to firePropertyChange() but XJC generates only simple setters, this.value = value.
2. XJC properties are protected, so it looks like I could override its setters to firePropertyChange(), but I don't know how my overriding subclass could have its unmarshaled superclass magically change state at runtime (like when user requests report for different year which is when I would unmarshal a different XML file).

Is there an example or pattern for doing this?  Surely it is not new.  Many thanks.  -d

Comment: You could try using XJC the other way around: declare your Java classes with the necessary annotations and generate the XML-schema from them. This way you can implement the setters needed for UI binding. Given that you bind it to a UI, you will only use a set of attributes/elements and you need to write code anyways when the displayed part of the schema changes. New XML elements won't bother JAXB unmarshalling; they will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

@Adam Thanks! I grokked a workable solution with this:

```
public class MyBean extends JaxBean {
  public JaxBean getJaxBean() {
    return this;
  }
  public void setJaxBean(JaxBean jaxBean) {
    super.setThis(jaxBean.getThis());
    super.setThat(jaxBean.getThat());
    // etc...
  }
  public MyBean() {
    // etc...
  }
}
```

I think my confusion was thinking the unmarshalled bean would somehow magically replace my working instance.  The solution above requires additional text but it works and the use of JaxBean's dumb setters avoids firing events unnecessarily when loading a new XML.

Your solution, annotating MyBean with JAXB and using schemagen, sounds even better. I will try that next go around. These are very nice technologies. -d

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned another approach to your application in my comment.

It's what we use in our RCP application. Except that we marshall/unmarshall through network thus we use JAXWS and not just JAXB.

I'm somewhat experienced with this kind of stack, so here's a kick-starter for you:

```
/**
 * Your UI POJO-s should extend this class.
 */
public abstract class UIModel<T extends UIModel> {
    protected final PropertyChangeSupport propertyChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    /**
     * This comes handy at times
    */
    public void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller unmarshaller, Object parent) {
        //....
    }

    /**
     * And this too, trust me.
     */
    public void deepCopy(final T of) {
            removePropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeListener);

            //It's from Spring Framework but you can write your own. Spring is a fat-ass payload for a Java-SE application.
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(of, this, IGNORED_ON_CLIENT);

            addPropertyChangeListener(propertyChangeListener);
        }
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertyChangeSupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }
}

/**
 * Example of a UI POJO.
 */
public class Car extends UIModel<Car> {
    private String make;
    private int numberOfWheels;
    //... etc.

    /**
     * Example of a setter
     */
    public void setMake(String make) {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("make", this.make, this.make = make);
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }
    //... etc.
}
```

I don't know how often your Schema-definition changes but there's a pattern supporting this;

```
/**
 * New application (compiled with the class below) can open a file saved by the old application.
 */
public class Car2 extends Car {
    private String fuelType; // Example of a new field

    public void setFuelType(String fuelType) {
        propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("fuelType", this.fuelType, this.fuelType = fuelType);
    }

    //... etc.
}
```

This way the old application can open XML-outputs of the new. Dropping a field from such a class's source code will result in a RuntimeException as JAXB is still looking for it.
If you're clients are always up-to-date then you should not care about this at all.

When tackling with Java collections and subclassing excessively you will run into JAXB problems which you can solve by Googling @XmlRootElement and @XmlSeeAlso annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Comments don't format, trying "answer".  Need to do the stackoverflow tour.  Continuing,

---

Thanks, Adam, I will bookmark these for future reference. They look similar to my example, the pattern is (unmarshal New, be quiet, copy New to Old, be noisy). I like the mind-bending recursion,

```
class UIModel<T extends UIModel>
class Car extends UIModel<Car>
```

and assume you've tested it compiles. ;)

Regards, -d.